# Separate First Post Loop

Tags: loop, query-posts

I'm trying to use the `<?php rewind_posts(); ?>` feature to use two loops on my homepage template.  Does anyone know how to stop the first loop after the latest post?

Here is my Code:

```
<?php 

            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

            <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :

                    if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                        ?>
                            <header>
                                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text">
                                    <?php single_post_title(); ?>
                                </h1>
                            </header>
                            <?php
                    endif;

                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-home', get_post_type() );

                    endwhile;

                    the_posts_navigation();

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

                endif;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this which fill skip first post:

```
$i = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    if($i > 0)
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-home', get_post_type() );
    else {
        // design your first post as you wish with HTML, CSS
        the_title();
        the_permalink();
        the_post_thumbnail();   
        the_content();
        the_author();
        the_date();
    }           
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output the first post outside of a loop, then loop over the remaining posts:

```
if( have_posts() ){

    // first post output
    the_post();
    the_title();

    while( have_posts() ){
        // the rest
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like more the option and syntax of `current_post`:

```php
// First post inside loop
if( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) { 
            
}
```

See the WordPress Codex for more details: [Object orientation of the Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Object_orientation)